# PHP processing large form

Tags: php, email, csv

I am having difficulty in saving all post data to csv file and emailing the values to an address.  I have over 125 post variables and im quite stuck.  Here is a sample of my code thus far:

```
<?php
$x23 = "date";
$x24 = "fclose";
$x25 = "fopen";
$x26 = "fwrite";
$x27 = "mail";
$x28 = "time";
extract($_POST);
$a1 = $_POST['fname'];
$a2 = $_POST['lname'];
$a3 = $_POST['email'];
$a4 = $_POST['landline'];
$a5 = $_POST['mobile'];
$a6 = $_POST['addr1'];
$a7 = $_POST['addr2'];
$a8 = $_POST['towncity'];
$a9 = $_POST['postcode'];
$x1d = $a1 . "," . $a2 . "," . $a3 . "," . $a4 . "," . $a4 . "," . $a5 . "," . $a6 . "," . $a7 . "," . $a8 . "," . $a9 . "
";
$quotation = $x25("file5.csv", "a");
$x26($x1d, $quotation);
$x24($x1d);
header('Location: mydomain.co');
$x20 = 'mail@mydomain.com';   
$x22 = 'Quotation - My Company';
$x27($x20, $x21, $x23, $x1f);
?>
```

I have not put all variables in this question (not sure how to do this, but I think fputcsv() would do the job, to save all the 125 variables being written, but Iv'e never much used PHP and not sure on arrays and fputcsv()).

How would I loop through all my post variables and append them to csv as one row?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If all variables are put to csv you can use foreach loop, but you should to put it in right sequence. Is it a question problem?

Comment: You can add a "csv_" prefix to the name attribute of the inputs you are getting via POST. Then you will just need to check the presence of the prefix while you loop on $_POST

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is `implode`. It implodes an array into a single string with a specific "glue", in this case ','.

So, the simplest way is to use `implode(',', $_POST)`, but in case not all of the values are supposed to be used, there's a nice way to handle it by changing the names of the form elements.

In the form, if you change the name from `"fname"` into `"data[fname]"` and do the same for the rest of the elements, then `$_POST['data']` will be an array that holds all of the values. Then using `implode(',', $_POST['data'])` will make sure only desired values are used.

Answer (score 0):

You first of all need to be disciplined about solving one problem at a time.

```
(1) Create the CSV data in a variable
(2) Write the data to a file
(3) Send an email
(4) Include an attachment in the email
```

Or even break it down into more steps. Trying to solve a bunch of problems all at once is only going to get yourself more confused, especially if you are just getting started on programming.

So let's solve the "create the CSV" file.

You can easily loop through your `$_POST` and create a CSV file like this:

```
$csv_line = '';
$sep = ''; // don't put a comma before the 1st element
foreach ($_POST as $k -> $v) {
    $csv_line .= $sep . "\"$v\"";
    $sep = ','; // put a comma before the 2nd, 3rd, etc. elements
}
```

However, there are at least 2 problems with this. You may not want EVERY element in your $_POST to be put into the CSV, and there is no guarantee of the order those elements within $_POST.

So we'll create a separate array with just the fields we are interested in and making sure they are in the order we want to keep it:

```
$myFields = array('email', 
                  'fname', 
                  'lname', 
                  'junk', 
                  ...);
$csv_line = '';
$sep = ''; // don't put a comma before the 1st element
foreach ($myFields as $k) {
    $csv_line .= $sep . "\"$_POST[$k]\"";
    $sep = ','; // put a comma before the 2nd, 3rd, etc. elements
}
```

Now all you have to do is write out that line into a file, figure out how to send an email, and figure out how to attach the file to the email. But at least you are one step closer...